# Mysterious reference to empty constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here's my header file Normal.h:

```
#ifndef NORMAL_H
#define NORMAL_H

#include "Vector3.h"

class Normal
{
public:
   Vector3 pos;
   Vector3 direction;

   Normal(Vector3, Vector3);
};

#endif
```

Here's the cpp file Normal.cpp:

```
#include "Normal.h"
#include "Vector3.h"

Normal::Normal(Vector3 pos, Vector3 direction)
{
   this->pos = pos;
   this->direction = direction;
}
```

They are referencing a `Vector3` class which does not have a constructor that takes no arguments. The only constructor specified takes 3 ints.

But I get an error when I try to run a test:

```
g++ Normal.cpp -o NormalTest.cpp 
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccxgbatN.o: In function `Normal::Normal(Vector3, Vector3)':
Normal.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `Vector3::Vector3()'
```

I don't understand the error that says I have an undefined reference to 'Vector3::Vector3()' It looks like it's referring to this line: `Normal::Normal(Vector3 pos, Vector3 direction)`

I'm not fluent in C++, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an uncommon C++ issue.

To fix it try

```
Normal::Normal(Vector3 pos, Vector3 direction): pos(pos), direction(direction)
{
}
```

The reason is that the way you defined your constructor, C++ says:

1. Create a Normal object whose fields are initialized to their default values
2. Then *assign* the fields.

But what are the default values of `pos` and `direction`?  They are found by calling the default constructor of `Vector3`... but none is defined!  Hence the error.

The alternative version of the constructor, using initializers instead of assignment, works as follows:

1. Create a Normal object initializing fields on the fly with the copy constructor for its fields.

Assuming you have a copy constructor for `Vector3`, you should be okay.

In general writing constructors with initializers instead of assignment statements is a good idea, for this very reason.

Comment: There _is_ a default constructor declared - the definition isn't being linked in, however. This is the OP's primary problem (although it's good to mention the copy constructor thing as well)

Comment: @bdonlan The OP stated "They are referencing a Vector3 class which does not have a constructor that takes no arguments. The only constructor specified takes 3 ints."  In that case the default no-arg constructor that would be generated becomes unavailable

Comment: @Ray, look at the error message. It's a linker error, not a compiler error, so the compiler thinks a zero-arg destructor has been declared - and it's not the default implementation either.

Comment: Oh you're right!  I missed that error message before!  Nice. +1.  (Had the zero-arg constructor been truly hidden, there indeed would have been a compiler error "error: no matching function for call to ‘Vector3::Vector3()’".)

Answer (score 1):

In the g++ command that you ran, the compiler first compiles and then creates an executable by linking all dependencies (which is Vector3 in the case of Normal).

So, assuming there is Vector3.cpp, you should be doing something like this

```
g++ Normal.cpp Vector3.cpp -o NormalTest
```

or

```
g++ -c Normal.cpp
g++ -c Vector3.cpp
g++ Normal.o Vector3.o -o NormalTest
```

Next, should and executable be created out of 1 or more .cpp files, then at least one of the files should contain a 'main' method. So, add a main method to either Normal.cpp or Vector3.cpp to get rid of the "undefined reference to Main" error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't define a `main` function anywhere, the entry point, the function that calls everything else.

   Your invocation of the compiler, `g++ Normal.cpp -o NormalTest.cpp`, tells it to compile `Normal.cpp` and produce an executable (which it is to name `NormalTest.cpp`, which is wrong in at least two ways), but it can't because `Normal.cpp` in particular has no `main` function.

   Your `Vector3` class has a constructor that takes three arguments. Ordinarily the compiler will provide a default constructor (i.e. one that takes no arguments) for any class you invent, **but** if you define a constructor that *does* take arguments, then the compiler will *not* provide a default constructor. (This is a part of the C++ language, not a compiler issue.) If you don't define a constructor for `Vector3` that takes no arguments, then you must design your `Normal` constructor to construct the member `Vector3`'s with the constructor you *have* provided.

   Start with HelloWorld. Always start with HelloWorld.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to consider storing pointers rather than copying objects as you are doing now.  What your constructor is implicitly trying to do is to construct two empty Vector3's and then to copy the contents of the arguments (pos, direction) into those empty Vector3's that are the member variables of Normal.

These members are embedded objects, not pointers.

The implicit calls to the empty constructor Vector3() are caused by the existence of these embedded objects.

It's more typical to store pointers, so you might declare something like:

```
class Normal
{
public:
   Vector3 *pos;
   Vector3 *direction;

   Normal(Vector3*, Vector3*);
};
```

but if you insist on embedding the objects, I think there is a syntax to call the Vector3 constructor from the Normal constructor.  It's like this:

```
Normal::Normal(Vector3 p, Vector3 dir) : pos(p), direction(dir) { }
```